# Why would adding targetFramework="4.5" to httpRuntime in web.config make my decryption key invalid?

Tags: asp.net, iis, encryption, web-config, machinekey

I've added IIS Web Sockets into my site recently. To do this I had to add the `targetFramework="4.5"` into the `httpRuntime` tag of the web.config.

Unfortunately, now when I try and log in to my site I get the following error:

> Decryption key specified has invalid hex characters.

The machineKey in my web.config file is as follows:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="513A71A2266CD92E99AA2970F18AE3F8A14DE3625BDD5792FB4AC15F9004693D,IsolateApps" validationKey="FBC9407A7ECE1C60741B44303670247CBE2E08B0658ED1031CF4A2582BDDFA4CD2E27201B083A5DF39C56C2D5B91674BD4FAB2EE644FB067D2C43633D3E6A724,IsolateApps" />
</system.web>
```

Does anyone know why adding targetFramework would cause this issue, and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

After looking further it appears it is the ,IsolateApps that is the issue. Before targetFramework was added, IsolateApps was fine in the machineKey, but with 4.5 added it is seen as no longer valid.

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="513A71A2266CD92E99AA2970F18AE3F8A14DE3625BDD5792FB4AC15F9004693D" validationKey="FBC9407A7ECE1C60741B44303670247CBE2E08B0658ED1031CF4A2582BDDFA4CD2E27201B083A5DF39C56C2D5B91674BD4FAB2EE644FB067D2C43633D3E6A724" />
</system.web>
```